# my program is not returning the answer in C#. help please

Tags: c#

This is the class that I created to check the activity of mosquitoes and When I call it in the main function I am not getting the output.

```
public class Mosqactivity
{
    public string Mating (int age)
    {
        string a ="";
        if (age==12)
        {
            a="mosquito is in mating";
        }
        return a;
    }
    public string Blood (int age)
    {
        string b ="";
        if (age==13||age==14)
        {
            b="Searching blood";
        }
        return b;
    }
    public string Resting (int age)
    {
        string c ="";
        if (age==15||age==16||age==17)
        {
            c="Resting";
        }
        return c;
    }
    public string Layeggs (int age)
    {
        string d="";
        if (age==18||age==23||age==28)
        {
            d="Lay Eggs";

        }
        return d;
        
    }
}
```

code in the main function

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int day=0;
    Mosqactivity act;
    act = new Mosqactivity ();
    string result="";
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number \n");
    Console.ReadLine(); result=act.Mating(day);
    result=act.Layeggs(day);
    result=act.Blood(day);
    result=act.Resting(day);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the code to give output like 'Mosquito is mating" or Search for blood or Resting or Lay eggs as it is checking in the function, but after entering the number it finish the process.

Comment: try adding a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end, so the program _doesn't close_ once it's done.

Comment: You overwrite your result everytime. If the day is not 15-17, you return an empty string for the last call (Resting). To have mor output, you should add the Console.WriteLine after every Mosqactivity call (Mating/Layegss and so on)

Comment: You are overwriting the result each time. Only the last one in `Resting` survives.

Comment: You are never assigning a value different from `0` to `day` ... And you are always overwriting your `result`, ie the result printed will always be the result of `act.Resting(day)`, and as `day == 0` this will always be an empty string

Answer (score 4):

many issues in code but here the relevant ones:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

is maybe reading some input but you are missing the assignment to a variable in code...
so in the end, you are calling all the methods with the parameter int day=0;

No method at all is having a check for the case day == 0 (actually 'age', coz you named the parameter like that) so all those are returning an empty string

additionally to this, you are printing only the last assignment of the "result" variable.

```
result=act.Layeggs(day);
result=act.Blood(day);
result=act.Resting(day);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

instead you should do somethin like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Layeggs? " + act.Layeggs(day));
```

or

```
result = act.Layeggs(day);
Console.WriteLine("Layeggs? " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

support this is testing code,right?
you can add Console.WriteLine after each act.Method(), you can see the output.

the first three invoking are overwrited by the last

```
result=act.Mating(day);
result=act.Layeggs(day);
result=act.Blood(day);
result=act.Resting(day);
```